# How could create and push a docker image of an application with multiple dockerfiles?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have a docker application with multiple dockerfiles. Each file is in sepearte sub-directory of the project.
A dockercompose file is created under the root directory. Please see project as below:

[image]

My question is how to build an image from the application and push it then to docker Hub?

Answer (score 0):

First of all: **docker compose** builds a docker stack, where each service is a single docker image.

By `docker-compose push` command you can push each separate docker image.

Comment: this will push different images each for a service isn't? what if I want to create an image that combines those three services is it possible?

Comment: No, as I stated each service is a single image which have to be pushed to the hub.